# Насколько безопасны хеши SHA3?

Tags: криптография, хеширование

В основном интересует SHA3-512, насколько безопасен этот алгоритм? Что лучше sha2-256 или sha3-512?

Comment: Зависит от того, как и для чего вы собрались его применять

Comment: Странный вопрос. Очевидно, что SHA3 лучше, так как его придумали на замену SHA2.

Comment: Да, но SHA3 появился позже sha2 и возможно не успел себя зарекомендовать. Спрашиваю, т.к раньше не пользовался SHA3, но думаю перейти на него.

Comment: Переходите, как минимум в SHA3 исправили length extension attack, которая была в SHA2

Comment: *"По жизни"*, на самом деле все они одинаковы (даже MD5) (не слушайте теоретиков-параноиков, на практике кражи-взломы делают совсем не теми способами)